# CWSIT0086E: Bus not found error while trying to send message

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, websphere-8

I am trying connect to JMS queues configured on a Websphere Application Server 8 with the help of a standalone java code. But I am receiving an exception. i checked http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK78897 this link but did not get any solution.
SSL is disabled on the remote server.
PFB my code and the stack trace.

```
package com.jms.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    System.out.println("Start.....");
    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://10.10.222.197:2810");
    //String pUrl = System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
    //System.out.println("*******"+pUrl+"********");
    InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext(environment);
    System.out.println("Init Done");

    QueueConnectionFactory qConFac =  (QueueConnectionFactory)initContext.lookup("jms/FOREIGN.DIRECT.QCF");
    System.out.println("Connection Factory is - "+qConFac.toString());

    Queue queue = (Queue) initContext.lookup("jms/FOREIGN.DIRECT.Q");
    System.out.println("Queue is - "+queue.toString());

    initContext.close();

    //System.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.performURLHostNameVerification", "true");

    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    TextMessage txtMessage = null;
    Message message = null;

    try {
        connection = qConFac.createConnection();
        System.out.println("CONNECTION OBTAINED");

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println("SESSION CREATED");

        System.out.println("Please enter your message:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String msg = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Creating producer to send message...");
        producer = session.createProducer(queue);

        System.out.println("Creating a TextMessage...");
        txtMessage = session.createTextMessage(msg);
        producer.send(txtMessage);

        System.out.println("Text Message sent to queue.");

        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        System.out.println("CONSUMER CREATED");
        connection.start();
        txtMessage = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
        String receivedMsg = txtMessage.getText();
        System.out.println("Message received is "+receivedMsg);

        if(receivedMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            System.out.println("Ticket Number is 1");
        else if(receivedMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            System.out.println("Ticket Number is 2");
        else
            System.out.println("Some other message was received");


    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //System.out.println("JMS Exception while creating connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Stack Trace:

```
Start.....
Init Done
JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file is not set.
Connection Factory is - com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsQueueConnectionFactoryImpl@a26cf1a1
Queue is - queue://FOREIGN.DIRECT.Q?busName=FOREIGN.DIRECT.TEST
Exception in thread "P=92841:O=0:CT" com.ibm.websphere.sib.exception.SIErrorException: CWSIT0008E: A successful connection was made to the bootstrap server at localhost:7276:BootstrapBasicMessaging but the server returned an error condition: CWSIT0086E: Bus FOREIGN.DIRECT.TEST not found
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.generateException(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:982)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.remoteBootstrap(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:638)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createCoreConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:711)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createCoreConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:647)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsJcaConnectionFactoryImpl.java:376)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:162)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:135)
at com.jms.test.Demo.main(Demo.java:50)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.sib.exception.SIErrorException: CWSIT0009W: A client connect to bus FOREIGN.DIRECT.TEST failed in the bootstrap server with endpoint localhost:7276:BootstrapBasicMessaging with reason: CWSIT0086E: Bus FOREIGN.DIRECT.TEST not found.
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.generateException(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1035)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.contactBootstrapService(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:745)
at com.ibm.ws.sib.trm.client.TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.remoteBootstrap(TrmSICoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:589)
... 8 more
```

Comment: Is the bus `FOREIGN.DIRECT.TEST` created? Do you have any servers added to the bus? Is the messaging engine correctly initialized?

Comment: Yes, the bus is created and messaging engine is also running. 
This issue is also resolved in Provider endpoints 'localhost:7276:BootstrapBasicMessaging', I replaced localhost with the ip of the machine